# Regex, match anything between two strings

Tags: java, regex

I feel like this is trivial but can't find any solution that works for me.

I have a string of this sort :

`cn=doc_medical,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=doc_confidentiel,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr`

Where I need to to find the value between `cn=` and `,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr`, in this case I should only match `doc_medical` first and `doc_confidentiel` then.

I have this regex : `(?=cn=)(.*?)(?<=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)` but the problem is that it obviously matches everything after the second `cn=` of the global string until the next `,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr`. So my second group is wrong because it contains `cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=doc_confidentiel,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr` instead of only `doc_confidentiel`.

I don't know the number of character there can be between the two strings, and I can't seem to figure out how to force the regex to match the first `cn=` previous to the `,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr` string instead of the first one it encounters after it.

Comment: `.*(cn=.*?,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)` or `cn=(?:(?!cn=).)*?,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the first one doesn't work, the second one gives me the whole string `cn=doc_medical,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr` (and the second one) whereas I would only like `doc_medical` and `doc_confidentiel`.

Comment: Then use `(?<=cn=)[^,|]+(?=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)`, see https://regex101.com/r/RUjCRp/3 and https://regex101.com/r/RUjCRp/3/codegen?language=java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=cn=)[^,|]+(?=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RUjCRp/3).

*Details*:

- `(?<=cn=)` - a location immediately preceded with `cn=`
- `[^,|]+` - one or more chars other than `|` and `,`
- `(?=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr` string to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/77WGnW):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String regex = "(?<=cn=)[^,|]+(?=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)";
        String string = "cn=doc_medical,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=doc_confidentiel,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
doc_medical
doc_confidentiel
```

**NOTE**: If there is a value other than `cn` that can contain more chars on the left, use a word boundary: `(?<=\bcn=)[^,|]+(?=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)`. In Java, `String regex = "(?<=\\bcn=)[^,|]+(?=,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr)";`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex replacement approach here:

```java
String input = "cn=doc_medical,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=doc_confidentiel,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr";
String cn = input.replaceAll(".*\\bcn=([^,]+),ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr.*", "$1");
System.out.println(cn);  // doc_confidentiel
```

Note that in your current regex pattern, which uses lookarounds, you seemed to be confusing lookbehinds with lookaheads.  But, the approach I gave above doesn't even need lookarounds.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't give me `doc_medical` and `doc_confidentiel` it only gives me `doc_confidentiel`, am I missing something or was I unclear in my question ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capture group, and for example not cross matching a pipe `|` char

```
\bcn=([^|]*),ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xn8S4K/1)

If it is the first value after the cn= then not matching a comma could also work:

```
\bcn=([^,]*),ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bcn=` Match the word `cn` and then =
- `([^,]*)` Capture group 1, optionally match any char that you do not allow
- `,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr\b` Match the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sArFtZ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GKSpB0)

For example

```
String regex = "\\bcn=([^,]*),ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr\\b";
String string = "cn=doc_medical,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=doc_confidentiel,ou=tged,ou=groupes,o=choregie,c=fr|cn=test,ou=test,ou=test,o=choregie,c=fr";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
doc_medical
doc_confidentiel
```